# How do I remove space between rows in my Bootstrap design?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spacing

I am working on a responsive website and I can't seem to figure out why there is a space between the two bottom rows on my webpage. See:

http://test.kmcmarine.com/

I'd like to remove the space between the bottom red line and the footer. Can somebody please help me?

Thanks!
Nancy

Comment: Your red-bar image is displayed `inline`, the space is reserved for letter descenders. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5804278/1612146).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Nancy :) When asking questions seeking debugging help, please provide the relevant codes along with your description of the issue. Also, do check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to ask questions here in SO.

Comment: Thank you both! Sorry about not providing all the necessary information! I'm still learning. :)

Comment: Thank you, George! Changing the display from inline to block did the trick! This is all very new to me. Thanks so much for this great advice. I've struggled with this for many hours! :D I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to reduce the font size in that specific div by adding font-size 1px like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" style="font-size: 1px">
     <img src="Images/red line.gif" class="img-responsive">
 </div>
```

Or maybe even better to add display block for the img element:

```
<img src="Images/red line.gif" class="img-responsive" style="display: block">
```